# Dump `show slave status` into the table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Is it possible to dump results of the `show slave status` by using MySQL commands? I understand that I can use kind of script that would parse this result and insert into the table, however is it possible to do that with the MySQL query only?

UPDATED: I can't use `performance_schema` as it is not enabled now and enabling it requires reboot which we can't do right now.

Comment: No need to dump this data into any table, just use performance schema's replication tables https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-replication-tables.html

Comment: @Shadow I queried every single table from that article (both on master and replica) and there is no data in any of them.

Comment: Then you need to enable performance schema. See mysql manual on how to do that.

Comment: The question still remain, we can't enable `performance_schema` now

Comment: Then you are out of luck. That's the way mysql provides to access the same information via select queries.